# Редирект 301 с *.html на php

Tags: .htaccess

Есть файлы *.php.

Нужно сделать так чтоб в строке браузера были УРЛы типа *.html, но чтобы всё так же замечательно отрабатывало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php") header ("Location: /index.html");

или в .htaccess

Redirect 301 /index.php http://адрес сайта/index.html
```

Задавайте корректно вопрос, получайте корректно ответ.

Comment: плюсики Вам поставлю) верное решение будет ниже.

Answer (score 3):

Создаешь файл .htaccess и добавляешь туда:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

На сервере должен быть включен модуль rewrite. Это в случае, если Вы используете Apache.

Comment: это у меня было написано до Вас. Суть в том, что когда вводишь /index.php должен случиться редирект на index.html. Пользователь должен увидеть site.ru/index.html, но при этом должен отработать файл index.php

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(favicon.ico)

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1\.php [L,C]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1\.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Отвечу плюсиком конечно же, но коммент  автора к первому ответу на столько разбежен с самим вопросом что догадывайся что именно ему нужено)

Comment: ок. просто сверхсрочно нужно было. в торопях не смог ясно выразить свои мысли. прошу прощения. исправлюсь)